# Cannot register notification blocks from within write transactions

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, realm

I am trying to add notification block for my object like this:

```
self.tokenChat = [self.chat addNotificationBlock:^(BOOL deleted, NSArray<RLMPropertyChange *> * _Nullable changes, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!deleted && ![weakSelf.chat isInvalidated]) {
            [weakSelf.tableMes reloadData];
            }
}];
```

But having error like: `Cannot register notification blocks from within write transactions.`

What's possible reasons for this behaviour?

Answer (score -3):

Realm does not allow create observers within write transactions. More details in this [thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4701).